# C# UWP - Creating an ItemTemplate dynamically from an OrderedList

Tags: c#, uwp, datatemplate, uwp-xaml

I've found lots of posts on dynamic DataTemplates for WPF, but none for UWP.

My data is arbitrary JSON, meaning the key/value pairs are not predefined in my code. I need to be able to create a DataTemplate that matches the selected item, based on its key/value pairs.

How can I accomplish this? My data looks like this:
[image]

The sublevel OrderedDictionary will have arbitrary key/value pairs, as well as the parent OrderedDictionary. This is as complex as my data structure will be (for now, at least).

Update for clarification:

This is what my data looks like - the application loads this JSON and builds the UI from the JSON contents. The code *doesn't know what the keys are* - my DataTemplate needs to be dynamic, with the bindings for the template created when the file is loaded into the application.

```json
{
    "template" : {
        "example" : {
            "name" : "Name",
            "wigglies" : [
                {
                    "displayname" : "Artifact Spots"
                }
            ],
            "othersrc" : [
                {
                    "displayname" : "Other Sources"
                }
            ],
            "reward" : "Donation Reward",
            "drops" : [
                {
                    "displayname" : "Monster Drops"
                }
            ],
            "price0base" : "Base Price",
            "edibility" : "Edibility",
            "iridium" : "",
            "image" : ""
        },
        "metadata" : {
            "author" : "Me",
            "version" : "1.0",
            "published" : "12/21/2019"
        }
    },
    "content" : {
        "categories" : [
            {
                "category" : "Artifacts",
                "subcategories" : [
                    {
                        "subcategory" : "Artifacts",
                        "items" : [
                            {
                                "name" : "Amphibian Fossil",
                                "wigglies" : [
                                    {
                                        "name" : "Forest"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name" : "Mountain"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "othersrc" : [
                                    {
                                        "name" : "Fishing Treasure Chest"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "price0base" : "150"
                            },
                            {
                                "name" : "Anchor",
                                "wigglies" : [
                                    {
                                        "name" : "The Beach"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "othersrc" : [
                                    {
                                        "name" : "Fishing Treasure Chest"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name" : "Artifact Trove"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "price0base" : "100"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "category" : "Equipment",
                "subcategories" : [
                    {
                        "subcategory" : "Refining",
                        "items" : [
                            {
                                "name" : "Charcoal Kiln"
                            },
                            {
                                "name" : "Crystalarium"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "subcategory" : "Artisan",
                        "items" : [
                            {
                                "name" : "Bee House"
                            },
                            {
                                "name" : "Cask"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the DataTemplate I've tried to use as a test. It doesn't seem to pick up the "name" value of a given object, even though every object has a "name" property.

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="TestTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0 5 0 20"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

```cs
// output this dictionary as a table
GridView grdItems = new GridView()
{
    Name = "GrdItems",
    ItemsSource = item,
    ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["TestTemplate"]
};
```

The result of the above looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You need to make a [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.DataTemplateSelector) to apply different dataTemplates for your list control by the different 'key/value'.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share your code?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - I've updated the original question with more details.

Comment: @XavierXie - the problem is, I don't want to use explicit data bindings in my application's XAML, because the entities are arbitrary and are sourced from the JSON the application loads.

Comment: If you want dynamic, you can't create a fixed class, you need to use Dictionary to parse your json. And you also can't predefined dataTemplate in xaml, can only manually create dataTemplate in code-behind based on your data, then pass your dataTemplate to your listView or gridView. In addition, if dataTemplate can't be created programmatically, you need to create listViewItem to display.